# Passing parameter using variable While generating DSC configuration

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, powershell-dsc

I am executing Powershell DSC script from Powershell. Below is the code snippet

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $public_ip_address -Credential $UserCredential -ScriptBlock {
    param ($driveformat)
    cd c:/provisioning
    Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force -Scope CurrentUser
    Install-Module -Name PSDscResources -Force
    Install-Module -Name xStorage -Force
    . .\DiskSetup.ps1
    disksconfig -outputpath C:\DataDiskSetting -driveFormat $driveFormat
    Start-DscConfiguration -Path C:\DataDiskSetting -Wait -Force -Verbose
} -ArgumentList ($driveformat)
```

While generating configuration I want to pass driveformat as variable "$driveFormat" instead of hardcoding like "NTFS". Somehow its not getting value of $driveformat any idea how we can solve this.

Comment: You don't show where you define `$driveformat`

Comment: It is passed as Parameter from pipeline in PS Script.

Comment: OK, how can we help you determine why it's empty?

Comment: Value is passed from Pipeline for example "NTFS"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a named **Parameter** `$driveformat` in your script. See below example:

```
Param([String]$driveformat)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $public_ip_address -Credential $UserCredential -ScriptBlock {
    param ($driveformat)
    ...
} -ArgumentList ($driveformat)
```

Then in the [powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) from pipeline, add `-driveformat "NTFS"` in the argument field. See below screenshot: (I defined a pipeline variable `driveformat` to hold the value "NTFS")

[image]

[image]

Or, you can add an Argument (eg. `$driveformat = $args[0]`) in your scripts. See below:

```
$driveformat = $args[0]

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $public_ip_address -Credential $UserCredential -ScriptBlock {
    param ($driveformat)
    ...
} -ArgumentList ($driveformat)
```

Then you can directly pass the variable ("NTFS") in the Arguments field of powershell task:

[image]